# How to remove specific divs from div content and send them for save?

Tags: jquery

I need help for remove specific divs from div content.

I have a html content like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="container">html content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div>html</div>
                <div>html</div>
                <div>html</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div>text</div>
                <div class="image-icon">
                    <img src="test.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do like this:

```
<div class="container">html content</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>html</div>
    <div>html</div>
    <div>html</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>text</div>
    <img src="test.png">
</div>
```

I need remove:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="image-icon"></div>
```

Here is my code:

```js
$("#save").click(function() {
    var data = $(".list").html();
    // $(".wrapper").find(".list, .item, .icon, .image-icon").remove();
    // $.post('save.php', {
    //     contents: data
    // });
    alert(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="container">html content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div>html</div>
                <div>html</div>
                <div>html</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="container">
            <div>text</div>
                <div class="image-icon">
                    <img src="test.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="save" value="SAVE" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8xo97dc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap) to remove wrapped elements and [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove) methods for removing empty elements where get empty elements using [`:empty` pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/).

```
// get all elements you want to remove
$('.wrapper,.list,.item,.icon,.image-icon')
  // filter out empty elements and remove
  .filter(':empty').remove()
  // back to the main selector
  .end()
  // get it's children elements(including textnode, commetnode... elements)
  .contents()
  // unwrap elements(will remove it's parent)
  .unwrap()
```

```js
var $main = $('#main');

$main.find('.wrapper,.list,.item,.icon,.image-icon')
  .filter(':empty').remove()
  .end()
  .contents()
  .unwrap();

console.log($main.html().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="container">html content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div>html</div>
          <div>html</div>
          <div>html</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div>text</div>
          <div class="image-icon"><img src="test.png"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I did try like this: `var data = $('.wrapper,.list,.item,.icon,.image-icon').filter(':empty').remove().end().contents().unwrap();` but I guess I did wrong? data content message: [object Object]

Comment: @webmaster : what are you expecting?

Comment: @webmaster : unwrap returns the unwrapped element( jquery object )

Comment: I am sorry for my bad English and my newbie JS skills. When I try your code data veriable turned to [object Object] with alert function. How can I get content like "how can I do like this" section in my question? Your code working very good on jsfiddle and what i need. But I don't know why not worked on my local, I am looking... Thank you again.

Comment: @webmaster : i'd added an additional wrapper with id main in stack snippet to get the html content( just to log the html)

Comment: Finally worked on my local too. Thank you so much. I updated my jsfiddle with your worked code. https://jsfiddle.net/e8xo97dc/